# Keep getting React this.setState is not a function although is binded

Tags: reactjs, bind, setstate

I keep getting this error message although I have already binded the called function. I have already tried binding at the constructor `this.onChangeEstablishmentSelected = this.onChangeEstablishmentSelected.bind(this)` and outside of it `onChange={this.onChangeEstablishmentSelected.bind(this)}`

I don't know what is causing it because it doesn't make any sense, and I have gone through many posts and the official docs and everything seems to me in place to me.

```
class PatientFormReview extends Component {

state = {
        materializeInitialized: false,
        establishmentId: 0
    };

onChangeEstablishmentSelected(event) {
    this.setState({
        establishmentId: event.target.value
    });
}

renderOptions() {
    if (this.props.auth.establishments.length === 1) {
        this.setState = {
            establishmentId: this.props.auth.establishments[0].id
        };
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <select value={this.state.establishmentId} disabled>
                    <option value={this.props.auth.establishments[0].id}>
                        {this.props.auth.establishments[0].name}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <label>Establecimiento</label>
            </Fragment>
        );
    } else {
        let options = this.props.auth.establishments.map(establishment => (
            <option key={establishment._id} value={establishment._id}>
                {establishment.name}
            </option>
        ));
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <select
                    value={this.state.establishmentId}
                    onChange={this.onChangeEstablishmentSelected.bind(this)}
                >
                    {options}
                </select>
                <label>Establecimiento</label>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting `this.setState` inside of `renderOptions` by writing `this.setState = { establishmentId: this.props.auth.establishments[0].id };`

Comment: @Tholle that's not the issue, because that part of the code is in the other segment of the if statement. Also I have a typo there because it should be `this.setState({ establishmentId: this.props.auth.establishments[0].id })`

Comment: If the question doesn't reflect you actual code, due to typo or copy/paste errors, it is best to edit the question so that it does and leave a quick note mentioning the change.